# add function code into specific php page

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to add this code into my theme's function.php

```
function custom_add_author() {
    $author = get_the_author();
    echo $author; 
}

add_action( '???', 'custom_add_author' );
```

I wanted to add this function code into the specific php named
"author-listing.php"

How can I add this using the correct code?
was it?

```
add_action( 'author-listing.php', 'custom_add_author' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If i read your question right..you can just use include() function.

For example at the top of author-listing.php, you can add:

```
include("function.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ment a wordpress theme, take alook at the official documentation at: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/ there are some more examples as well.

> To find out the number and name of arguments for an action, simply
>   search the code base for the matching do_action() call. For example,
>   if you are hooking into 'save_post', you would find it in post.php:
>
> `<?php do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post, $update ); ?>`
>
> Your add_action call would look like:
>
> `<?php add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post', 10, 3 ); ?>`
>
> And your function would be:
>
> `function my_save_post( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
>      // do stuff here
>   }`